# Did the Tattaglias know Luca Brasi was a spy?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-godfather

As far as I understand from *The Godfather*, Luca Brasi's loyalty wasn't known outside the Corleone family, and the exchange before he was murdered was pretty fast. The only thing I noticed is that Luca was pretty "slow" to react when he was proposed a notable amount of money.

Did Tattaglia know Luca was a spy, or did he simply kill him because of the rivalry with the Corleone family?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Did Tattaglia know Luca was a spy, or did he simply kill him because of the rivalry with the Corleone family?

It's not clear but it's likely that the reason was....

## Just In Case

There's no indication that Tattaglia **knew** Brasi was gathering intelligence and Brasi had never sworn any kind of loyalty to Tattaglia or denied his underlying loyalty to the Don.

> The first meeting was all above-board, Tattaglia offering him a job to work in the Family business as enforcer. The flirtation went on for nearly a month. Luca played his role of man infatuated with a young beautiful girl, Bruno Tattaglia the role of a businessman trying to recruit an able executive from a rival. At one such meeting, Luca pretended to be swayed, then said, “**But one thing must be understood. I will never go against the Godfather**. Don Corleone is a man I respect. I understand that he must put his sons before me in the Family business.”
>
> <sup>*The Godfather* - Mario Puzo</sup>

However, Brasi's **reputation** for violence was considerable and Tattaglia couldn't take the chance that Brasi might take action against him because of Brasi's loyalty to the Don.

So, from a tactical point of view, it makes sense to remove the potential "threat" of Brasi from the field.

Answer (score 2):

After rewatching the [scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02h8XHJ5dzM) I have the feeling that Tattaglia and Sollozzo considered the possibility of killing him (hence they hired the assassin) but they wasn't 100% sure that they would do it.

The "job interview" was also a way for them to test Luca's loyalty and they weren't convinced: **Luca's stays cold and refuses to shake Virgil's hand.** I've noticed the importance of touch contact (shaking hands, gangster-hugs, kisses...) in mob  movies, to notify loyalty. After Brasi's refusal, we can see their behaviour slightly change and, it seems, they send the subtle cue to the hitman to do it.

Maybe a more friendly Luca, shaking hands, would have convinced them to actually recruit him.

Comment: I just rewatched it and never noticed seeing the fishes in the window at 0:29.